# Run a script module with ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I've this task :

```
- name: script
  script: "scripts/script.sh"
```

And in this script I would like to use ansible var like {{myvar}}

Is that possible ?

THKS

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: :) I've already and it looks like its not working. I want to confirm or a workaround..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I am aware there isn't a way of directly using an Ansible variable within a [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/script_module.html), as you describe.

There are a number of different ways of achieving the behavior I think you're after.

The first option would be to write your script in such a way that the desired variable value can be passed in as an argument. As described in the script module docs:

> The script module takes the script name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments.

As such, you could run a script which takes the variable as an argument like:

```
- name: script
  script: scripts/script.sh {{myvar}}
```

Another option would be [template out](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) the script and use the Ansible [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html) module to  substitute the variable value directly into your script. You could then use either the [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_module.html) or [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html) Ansible modules to execute the script, configured from the template, on the remote node.

Comment: Thks, my var is a password so I will use the template solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long string with newlines or spaces, prefer use single quotas to pass it as one sting

Also you might find it useful endings of **stdout** or **stdout_lines**

```
- name: script
  script: "{{ role_path }}/scripts/script.sh '{{ myvar.stdout }}'"
```